# Android project doesn't see code in commonMain

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform

I've tested this project out https://github.com/touchlab/KMMBridgeSampleKotlin
and I've then created a shared module in my existing project (normal Android Project, not KMM enabled). I've tried both creating the module from scratch and also importing the module from the project above.

It seems that I can't access the `Shared` class from `commonMain` from my Android Project code, unless I move the class to `main`. In the above project, it works just fine having it in `commonMain`.

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong, but ... I have no idea what.

I'd copy-paste the build.gradle from the shared module, but it's exactly as the from from the project above https://github.com/touchlab/KMMBridgeSampleKotlin/blob/main/shared/build.gradle.kts

Any ideas on what else I need to setup/enable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply had to update my gradle dependencies. I updated the `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to something above `7.x` and also kotlin plugin to a higher version, `com.google.gms:google-services` to `4.3.x` and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can check:

Make sure that the shared module is included in the project settings. To do this, open the `settings.gradle` file in your project and add the following line:

```
include(":shared")
```

This will ensure that the shared module is included in the project.

Check the dependencies in your `build.gradle` file for the app module. Make sure that you have added the shared module as a dependency:

```
implementation(project(":shared"))
```

This will ensure that the app module has access to the classes in the shared module.

Make sure that the commonMain source set is configured correctly in the shared module's `build.gradle` file.

```
sourceSets {
    val commonMain by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation(...)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I already did all of these :( And it's still not seeing the class I created in the commonMain folder. I'm going crazy ! ANy other ideas ? :( I'm definitely doing something wrong ... but ... I have no idea what ....

Comment: @AndreiBogdan i have the same problem, did you fix it somehow?